# model learning with binary variable

Tags: r, regression, logistic

Let's say I collected data from a single mouse that either pressed a lever (1) or not (0). There were a total of 3 environments (`env`), and the mouse spent 10 minutes wandering (the `time` variable levels corresponds to each minute).

```
dat1 <- data.frame(time=rep(seq(1,10), times=3), response=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1, 0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1), run=rep(c(1,2,3), each=10))
```

I'd like to model the mouse's behavior across `time`, such that larger estimates indicate faster learning. Given that my dependent variable `response` is binary, I guess logistic regression is my only option, so I tried:

```
summary(glm(response ~ time, data=dat1, family="binomial")))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -4.8633     1.7654  -2.755  0.00587 **
time          0.9424     0.3223   2.924  0.00345 **
```

However, changing the data such that it simulates the mouse learning slower

```
dat2 <- data.frame(time=rep(seq(1,10), times=3), response=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1), run=rep(c(1,2,3), each=10))
    
summary(glm(response ~ time, data=dat2, family="binomial")))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -16.2691     7.6916  -2.115   0.0344 *
time          1.9912     0.9392   2.120   0.0340 *
```

The estimate for `time` is actually larger. What is the reason for this? And is this how I should set up my model if the aim is to determine how quick the mouse has learned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is certainly right. I think that when you changed your data, the main impact was to decrease the constant. In order to reach $p(t)=0.5$, your model need: $t_1=\frac{4.86}{0.94}=5.16$ minutes and $t_2=\frac{16.27}{1.99}=8.17$ minutes. So your mouse actually globally learns slower, despite the increase in coefficient for $t$. Basically, you increased its ability to learn through time ($\beta_t$ increased), but decreased its basic skill ($\beta_0$ decreased). In general, you can see that the predicted ability of your mouse to pull the lever is higher in model 1 for $t>\frac{-16.27+4.86}{0.94-1.99}=10.88$. So if you plot these probabilities $p(t)$ for both your models, you will be able to see that in model 1, the mouse is actually always more able to pull the lever during the first 10 minutes.

[image]

You can see that in model 2, the mouse learns quicker after some time, but this time creates a huge delay overall.

EDIT:

I think that what you are looking for is a kind of score. You can design many scores, depending on your objectives/understanding of your experiment.

For instance, you could create a score $S_i$ for each model $i$ which would represent the expected number of successes after a defined number of trials predicted by each model, i.e.:

$$S_i= \sum_{t=1}^{t_\max}p_i(t)$$

Or it could represent the predicted required time to reach a defined probability of success:

$$S_i=t_i^*\text{ where }t_i^* \text{ is defined by: } p_i(t_i^*)=p_\text{objective}$$

Or you could compute recursively the distribution of the total number of successes after $t$ trials $\forall t>0$ to use the average necessary time in order to obtain $n$ successes.

It is up to you to choose the scoring methodology which corresponds to your problem/objectives. These are a few ideas I could come up with.

Comment: @FPO great explanation, many thanks!! I think I understood the issue now. The fundamental question for me now is: is there any way I can meaningfully combine `β0` and `βt` in a way that describes the general ability of the mouse to learn? So, ideally, mouse1 would have a greater estimate than mouse 2, since it is almost always more able than mouse 2.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a few idead. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes that's very helpful. I'll just need to figure out how to compute those scores using R, but I'll ask another question. Many thanks!!

Comment: @locus [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73139550/4891738).

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, thanks! Your answer is the solution to FP0's second suggestion, right?, ie "represent the predicted required time to reach a defined probability of success"?

Comment: @locus Sort of, yes. If *time* starts from a low value and we steadily increase it. Sooner or later the probability will increase from 0 to the target one. This is one idea for numerical optimization, but not the logic used by `uniroot`.